# Remove Quesry string to url but value is sill be able to get

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have this url structure 
`http://dev.gba.com/bullion/types/minted-bar/?cat=gold`. 
the query parameter `cat=gold` is used by a function and i wanted to clean my url by restructuring it using htaccess to this url `http://dev.gba.com/bullion/types/minted-bar/gold` but i can still be able to get that parameter cat=gold. Any elp would be deeply appreciated.

Now i have this in my htaccess

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "cat=gold" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1/gold/? [R=301,L]`
which gives me the url structure /bullion/brands/gba/gold/ but i dont need it to redirect just modify the url

Comment: Disregard the "woocommerce" of the marked duplicate, that's the WP solution that will solve your problem. If not, then go for the .htaccess duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

WordPress `Dashboard > Settings > General`.
Find Site Address (URL), and remove /wordpress (or whatever your sub-directory is) from the URL.
Keep /wordpress in the WordPress Address (URL)

Comment: this is so far from what i want to achieve. this is way beyond Permalink settings in wordpress

Comment: Try this plugin
Remove Query Strings From Static Resources